# GLSL version error

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

As a part of my project I have to display animated 3d models in opengl window

I found a sample code for this purpose on http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html

I successfully compiled the code but while runtime i am getting following errors

```
  Status: VSmain shader compiled with errors
  Compilation details for VSmain shader:
  0:3(1): error: syntax error, unexpected VERSION

  Status: FSmain shader compiled with errors
  Compilation details for FSmain shader:
  0:3(1): error: syntax error, unexpected VERSION

  Status: Link failed
  Linkage details:
  linking with uncompiled shaderlinking with uncompiled shader
  Errors in shader compilation
  Error initializing the lighting technique
```

and also for the

```
  printf("%s \n",glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
```

it is returning null

I feel that the error is with the skinning.glsl file  which is as follows

```
#version 120
#define VERTEX_IN attribute


const int MAX_POINT_LIGHTS = 2;
const int MAX_SPOT_LIGHTS = 2;
 struct VSInput 
 {
vec3  Position;                                             
vec2  TexCoord;                                             
vec3  Normal;    
ivec4 BoneIDs;
vec4  Weights;
};

interface VSOutput
{                                                                                    
vec2 TexCoord;                                                                 
vec3 Normal;                                                                   
vec3 WorldPos;                                                                 
};

struct VSOutput1
{                                                                                    
vec2 TexCoord;                                                                 
vec3 Normal;                                                                   
vec3 WorldPos;                                                                 
};

const int MAX_BONES = 100;

uniform mat4 gWVP;
uniform mat4 gWorld;
uniform mat4 gBones[MAX_BONES];

shader VSmain(in VSInput VSin:0, out VSOutput VSout)
{       
mat4 BoneTransform = gBones[VSin.BoneIDs[0]] * VSin.Weights[0];
BoneTransform     += gBones[VSin.BoneIDs[1]] * VSin.Weights[1];
BoneTransform     += gBones[VSin.BoneIDs[2]] * VSin.Weights[2];
BoneTransform     += gBones[VSin.BoneIDs[3]] * VSin.Weights[3];

vec4 PosL      = BoneTransform * vec4(VSin.Position, 1.0);
gl_Position    = gWVP * PosL;
VSout.TexCoord = VSin.TexCoord;
vec4 NormalL   = BoneTransform * vec4(VSin.Normal, 0.0);
VSout.Normal   = (gWorld * NormalL).xyz;
VSout.WorldPos = (gWorld * PosL).xyz;                                
}



const int MAX_POINT_LIGHTS = 2;
const int MAX_SPOT_LIGHTS = 2;

struct BaseLight
{
vec3 Color;
float AmbientIntensity;
float DiffuseIntensity;
};

struct DirectionalLight
{
struct BaseLight Base;
vec3 Direction;
};

struct Attenuation                                                                  
{                                                                                   
float Constant;                                                                 
float Linear;                                                                   
float Exp;                                                                      
};                                                                                  

struct PointLight                                                                           
{                                                                                           
struct BaseLight Base;                                                                  
vec3 Position;                                                                          
Attenuation Atten;                                                                      
};                                                                                          

struct SpotLight                                                                            
{                                                                                           
struct PointLight Base;                                                                 
vec3 Direction;                                                                         
float Cutoff;                                                                           
};                                                                                          

uniform int gNumPointLights;                                                                
uniform int gNumSpotLights;                                                                 
uniform DirectionalLight gDirectionalLight;                                                 
uniform PointLight gPointLights[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];                                          
uniform SpotLight gSpotLights[MAX_SPOT_LIGHTS];                                             
uniform sampler2D gColorMap;                                                                
uniform vec3 gEyeWorldPos;                                                                  
uniform float gMatSpecularIntensity;                                                        
uniform float gSpecularPower; 


vec4 CalcLightInternal(struct BaseLight Light, vec3 LightDirection, VSOutput1 In)            
{                                                                                           
vec4 AmbientColor = vec4(Light.Color, 1.0f) * Light.AmbientIntensity;                   
float DiffuseFactor = dot(In.Normal, -LightDirection);                                     

vec4 DiffuseColor  = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);                                                  
vec4 SpecularColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);                                                  

if (DiffuseFactor > 0) {                                                                
    DiffuseColor = vec4(Light.Color, 1.0f) * Light.DiffuseIntensity * DiffuseFactor;    

    vec3 VertexToEye = normalize(gEyeWorldPos - In.WorldPos);                             
    vec3 LightReflect = normalize(reflect(LightDirection, In.Normal));                     
    float SpecularFactor = dot(VertexToEye, LightReflect);                              
    SpecularFactor = pow(SpecularFactor, gSpecularPower);                               
    if (SpecularFactor > 0) {                                                           
        SpecularColor = vec4(Light.Color, 1.0f) *                                       
                        gMatSpecularIntensity * SpecularFactor;                         
    }                                                                                   
}                                                                                       

return (AmbientColor + DiffuseColor + SpecularColor);                                   
}                                                                                           

vec4 CalcDirectionalLight(VSOutput1 In)                                                      
{                                                                                           
return CalcLightInternal(gDirectionalLight.Base, gDirectionalLight.Direction, In);  
}                                                                                           

vec4 CalcPointLight(struct PointLight l, VSOutput1 In)                                       
{                                                                                           
vec3 LightDirection = In.WorldPos - l.Position;                                           
float Distance = length(LightDirection);                                                
LightDirection = normalize(LightDirection);                                             

vec4 Color = CalcLightInternal(l.Base, LightDirection, In);                         
float Attenuation =  l.Atten.Constant +                                                 
                     l.Atten.Linear * Distance +                                        
                     l.Atten.Exp * Distance * Distance;                                 

return Color / Attenuation;                                                             
}                                                                                           

vec4 CalcSpotLight(struct SpotLight l, VSOutput1 In)                                         
{                                                                                           
vec3 LightToPixel = normalize(In.WorldPos - l.Base.Position);                             
float SpotFactor = dot(LightToPixel, l.Direction);                                      

if (SpotFactor > l.Cutoff) {                                                            
    vec4 Color = CalcPointLight(l.Base, In);                                        
    return Color * (1.0 - (1.0 - SpotFactor) * 1.0/(1.0 - l.Cutoff));                   
}                                                                                       
else {                                                                                  
    return vec4(0,0,0,0);                                                               
}                                                                                       
}                                                                                           

shader FSmain(in VSOutput FSin, out vec4 FragColor)
{                                    
VSOutput1 In;
In.TexCoord = FSin.TexCoord;
In.Normal = normalize(FSin.Normal);
In.WorldPos = FSin.WorldPos;                                                                 

vec4 TotalLight = CalcDirectionalLight(In);                                         

for (int i = 0 ; i < gNumPointLights ; i++) {                                           
    TotalLight += CalcPointLight(gPointLights[i], In);                              
}                                                                                       

for (int i = 0 ; i < gNumSpotLights ; i++) {                                            
    TotalLight += CalcSpotLight(gSpotLights[i], In);                                
}                                                                                       

FragColor = texture(gColorMap, In.TexCoord.xy) * TotalLight;     
}

program Lighting
{
vs(120)=VSmain();
fs(120)=FSmain();
};
```

You can get the entire code at the link given above .

Comment: "*I feel that the error is with the skinning.glsl file*" I have a similar feeling. But since we're not clairvoyant and therefore cannot actually *see* "skinning.glsl" unless you show it to us, it will have to remain a feeling and your question will go unanswered.

Comment: It maybe that I have just overslept the most recent of most recent development, but this `skinning.glsl` file (only to be discovered by follwing your link) doesn't even look like valid GLSL to me, but rather some kind of *"FXization"* of GLSL.

Comment: What GPU/driver combination are you using? What does GL Extensions Viewer (http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/) say about your machine supporting GLSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with Nvidia Graphics Card 
The problem was with the version of OpenGL and glsl . This code in particular seems to support only for version #330 or greater

To Run the code with Nvidia support :
optirun ./{executable}